# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and Hibernate and I have been trying to connect to the MySQL database using  Spring MVC and Hibernate 4. Have tried every thing and checked all the existing questions related to this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

This is my PersistenceConfig.java  class:

```
package config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"repository"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
    dataSource.setUsername("admin");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public Properties properties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

    return properties;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class<?>[] {model.PersonalInformation.class});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(properties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
}
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>darkside</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
                <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.M9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

following the answers to other related questions I checked my pom for conflicts but I believe there is non (I am new so I could be wrong).
using: mvn dependency:tree

```
C:\Users\Windows 10 (64-bit)\Desktop\workspace\Spring>mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ Spring ---
[INFO] darkside:Spring:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.39:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:jar:9.0.0.M9:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:9.0.0.M9:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.840 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-26T14:48:41+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/61M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been searching for hours I hope someone could help me resolve this problem.

**UPDATED**
the error as shown in my eclipse console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exceptionTranslation' defined in config.PersistenceConfig: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in config.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in config.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:536)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:310)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:122)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:78)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:96)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:308)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:434)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 35 more
```

Comment: Please provide whole stack trace with the error.

Comment: @MarekJeszka I updated the question. Thank you

Comment: Maybe it won't help but as first try i always clean my .m2 folder! It seems to be cleary a version issues..try also to remove from hibernate-commons-annotations and hibernate-annotations dependencies that maybe override other hibernate methods

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy I am using eclipse. How can I clean my .m2 folder. Should I remove all the files in C:\Users\Windows 10 (64-bit)\.m2

Comment: Yeah, but im telling you this in general, this helps you a lot, when you have dependencies issues, is something is common to do, to be sure there is nothing corrupted in the local repository go inside the .m2 and delete the repo content, maybe this time it won't fix anything but is a good best practice, we have an automation to clean it where i work :) DONT DELETE ALL THE .M2 or you will delete also the settings.xml just the repository content

Comment: @ ivoruJavaBoy have removed all the files in C:\Users\Windows 10 (64-bit)\.m2 and updated my project to download the dependencies again. But the problem still remains.